# Specified Cast is not valid on selecting combobox values

Tags: c#, winforms

I am a Newbie to the c#.I added few key value pair items into the `combobox`. When I ran the application,it showed me the initial key and value by default that are present in the `combobox`. But when I selected another item.I'm getting exception:

[image: Specified Cast is not valid]

Sorry my about English!! Thanks in advance.

```
public void Category_Load()
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        dict.Add(-1, "Select");
        dict.Add(0,"CR");
        dict.Add(1,"Analysis");
        dict.Add(2,"Misc");
        comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(dict, null);
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Key";
    }
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

     string value = ((KeyValuePair<int,string>)comboBox1.SelectedValue).Value.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show("" + value);
        int key = ((KeyValuePair<int, string>)comboBox1.SelectedValue).Key;
        MessageBox.Show("" + key);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `SelectedValue` holds the Value part of the selected item. Your cast is invalid since SelectedValue will return an `int` (in your case) and not a `KeyValuePair<int, string>`.

Use the `SelectedItem` property instead of the `SelectedValue` property.
To get the key, you can simply cast the value of `SelectedValue` to int.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

 string value = ((KeyValuePair<int,string>)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Value.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show("" + value);
    int key = (int)comboBox1.SelectedValue;
    MessageBox.Show("" + key);

}
```

Comment: But why on initial page load, system displayed the "Value" and "Key".

Comment: What if I change the code to                                                                                          comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";                                                           private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

 string value = ((KeyValuePair<int,string>)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Value.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show("" + value);
    int key = (int)comboBox1.SelectedValue;
    MessageBox.Show("" + key);

}

Comment: On the initial load or any other load it will display things finely. The error occurs when you are reading the `ValueMember`.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code you have:

```
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Key";
```

is instructing the combobox that the `ValueMember` is tied to the `Key`. Therefore, when you access the `SelectedValue` property of the combobox, it will return whatever type is the type for `Key` property. In your case that will be `int`. And since you are converting an `int` to `KeyValuePair<int, string>`, for obvious reasons, you are getting that exception.

`SelectedValue` returns the `ValueMember` so it will return `int` in your case.

`SelectedItem` returns the whole object so it will return `KeyValuePair<int, string>` in your case.